# Load Error in ruby while loading "need" gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

i m get load error while loading "need" gem in ruby and the gem is installed on system

```
require 'need'
need('filename.rb')
```

ERROR

/usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `gem_original_require': no such file to load -- need (LoadError)
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in`require'
    from /home/user/public_html/.../cron_processor.rb:4

Comment: Add the error to your question.

Comment: /usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in gem_original_require': no such file to load -- need (LoadError)
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:inrequire' from /home/user/public_html/.../cron_processor.rb:4

Comment: 1.8.7?  try adding this before the first require: require 'rubygems'

Comment: already added before all require statements

Comment: Does this happen when you run the rails server? Or when you run a rails runner? If it is a runner, is it being called from cron?

Comment: its a simple ruby file used in cron

Comment: cron often has a different PATH variable than your default system user, you can try using the Whenever gem to get around the issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the rubygems path in the error it looks like you're not using RVM to manage Ruby. This can lead to various issues with gems due to permissions. Or it is also possible there are multiple versions of Ruby installed. You can check this with `which -a ruby`. You can also view your gem variables with `gem env` to see where rails is looking for the gem installations. It may be a different from the directory that you installed the gem for the system.

If you don't want to install RVM you can change the gem env variables manually by updating your user bash file but unless you have a specific reason not to use RVM it will probably save you time.

You can also try `whereis ruby` to see the location of the default ruby for your user. If this is different from the path that is used for loading the ruby gems then you will get a load error because the gem doesn't exist for that version of ruby.